# Can you alter a statement in a javascript function after is run once

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time figuring this out. I'd like the xxp.run.pause(); to be replaced by xxp.run.play(); after the initial code below is actioned by a user once. I've tried creating a closure but I'm not sure I set it up right. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
doSkip: function() {
    XXP.run.removeListener('canper', XXP.Skip);
    XXP.run.currentTime = XXP.skipTo;
        XXP.run.pause(); // this is what I would like to change
    }
```

Comment: Give more information about your bug. Add tags also. What lib you are using etc...

Comment: Why don't you maintain a local state variable which tells you what was the previous action and you can decide which function to run using that variable. Instead of dynamically trying to call functions.

Comment: Maybe use a Generator? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2A

Answer (score 1):

You may set a flag somewhere which records whether or not the `doSkip` function has been called before:

```
var hasSkip = false;

doSkip: function() {
    XXP.run.removeListener('canper', XXP.Skip);
    XXP.run.currentTime = XXP.skipTo;
    if (!hasSkip) {
        XXP.run.pause();
        hasSkip = true;
    }
    else {
        XXP.run.play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the function in an IIFE with a persistent variable that checks to see if it's been paused. This has the advantage over having a separate variable elsewhere because `hasPausedOnce` is only needed for the `doSkip` function - no need to populate the outer scope (which can have readers of your code worrying about whether `hasPausedOnce` is going to be altered elsewhere)

```
doSkip: (() => {
  let hasPausedOnce = false;
  return function() {
    XXP.run.removeListener('canper', XXP.Skip);
    XXP.run.currentTime = XXP.skipTo;
    if (!hasPausedOnce) {
      XXP.run.pause();
      hasPausedOnce = true;
    } else XXP.run.play();
  };
})()
```